# How to remove dependency problem?

Tags: dependencies, g++

I'm trying to install offline g++ software on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for ecil: 
dpkg: error processing archive g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ sudo dpkg -r g++-4.4
(Reading database ... 164836 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing g++-4.4 (4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ sudo dpkg -i g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb 
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ sudo dpkg -i g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb 
dpkg: error processing archive g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ sudo dpkg -r g++-4.4
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove g++-4.4 which isn't installed
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ sudo dpkg -r g++-4.4
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove g++-4.4 which isn't installed
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ sudo dpkg -r g++-4.4
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove g++-4.4 which isn't installed
ecil@ECIL-HP:~$ cd Desktop/
ecil@ECIL-HP:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i g++-3.3_3.3.5-13_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package g++-3.3.
(Reading database ... 164820 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack g++-3.3_3.3.5-13_i386.deb ...
Unpacking g++-3.3 (1:3.3.5-13) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-3.3:
 g++-3.3 depends on gcc-3.3-base (>= 1:3.3.5-13); however:
  Package gcc-3.3-base is not installed.
 g++-3.3 depends on gcc-3.3 (>= 1:3.3.5-13); however:
  Package gcc-3.3 is not installed.
 g++-3.3 depends on gcc-3.3 (<< 1:3.3.6); however:
  Package gcc-3.3 is not installed.
 g++-3.3 depends on libstdc++5-3.3-dev (>= 1:3.3.5-13); however:
  Package libstdc++5-3.3-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package g++-3.3 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 g++-3.3
```

Comment: Why would you install an antiquated version of GCC?

Comment: Where the `g++-4.4.4_4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1_i386.deb` file located is?

Comment: Give the link which one should download and install using offile

Comment: Are you connect to the Internet? you can install recent version of g++. use `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8`

Comment: I am using offline so i don't known which one should download  plz help me

Comment: OP: Stop rolling back the edits. Without the formatting all the error messages you provide are hard to make sense of.'

Answer (score 0):

Unless you show us any error message, only suggestion is to use `gdebi` or open the deb in `Ubuntu Software Center` instead of using `dpkg`.

Comment: @muru answer is updated